# Problem with Django startproject: TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-3.1

Trying to run

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

and there occurs such problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/bin/django-admin", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 20, in handle
    super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 158, in handle
    template = Engine().from_string(content)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 136, in from_string
    return Template(template_code, engine=self)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 447, in parse
    filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 563, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 638, in __init__

    var, constant = match['var'], match['constant']
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not subscriptable
```

I guess there is a problem with versions, but don't know exactly what is it.

On version 1.8.6 everything is ok, but when I try to use

```
from django.urls import path, include
```

I see that there is no django.urls in this version.

So I'd like to use the latest version and will be grateful, if you can help me!

Python version:

```
Python 3.6.0a4
```

Comment: The problem is still unsolved, but creating project without venv helped me. Tried to reinstall pycharm, but the problem was still there. If smb knows what can probably help me, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use an unofficial version of django.
Hello, try this first, dont remove anything leave pip do it for you:

```
pip install -U django
```

Now After that rerun startproject command line